# Getting error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute, How can I set the selected index on a ListBox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have the following code to select either the next list item or the first list item in a ListBox:

```
if (ListBox.SelectedIndex == lst.Count - 1)
    ListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
else
    this.ListBox.SelectedIndex = ListBox.SelectedIndex + 1;
```

It's throwing the exception:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute
```

The reason the collection was modified is I need to modify the content of one of the list items. I find the list item that I need to modify, remove it at that index and re-add it at the same index.

Is there a way to modify the contents of the list box and still be able to set the SelectedIndex?

Comment: Cna you share the code you modify the collection

Comment: Why do you have to remove it if you are putting it back in the same index?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably down to the order of execution and when the property is read and written.

Try:

```
var idx = ListBox.SelectedIndex;

if (idx == lst.Count - 1)
    ListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
else
    this.ListBox.SelectedIndex = idx + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below:

```
var index=ListBox.SelectedIndex;
if (index == lst.Count - 1)
    ListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
else
    this.ListBox.SelectedIndex = index + 1;
```